# Error in XML : Empty XML namespace is not allowed

Tags: html, xml, matlab, namespaces, xml-namespaces

I,m trying to read a webpage ( which is dictionary webpage ) with  matlab and convert html data to text with extractHTMLText for get some  informations but MATLAB gives this error :
" Error in XML : Empty XML namespace is not allowed . "
Since I am not a professional programmer , I am not familiar with the namespace and its errors .
code :

```
    url='https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/river';
    options = weboptions('Timeout', 10);
    code = webread(url,options);
    textData = extractHTMLText(code);
```

complete error ( test is my script name ) :

```
    Error using htmlTree (line 67)
    Error in XML: xmlns:fb: Empty XML namespace is not allowed
    
    Error in extractHTMLText (line 40)
    tree = htmlTree(code);
    
    Error in test (line 12)
    textData = extractHTMLText(code)
```

As you can see , MATLAB has a problem only in the text analysis  section of the read web page ( empty namespace error ) .

Can anyone help me to fix this error ? Thanks .

note : I checked the " code " variable to see if the webread function worked right or not and then printed this variable in the command window . The variable contained the HTML code which means that there is probably no problem in the HTML code .

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the contents of the web page with curl, you'll see that it starts:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" xmlns:vcom xmlns:fb>
<head>
```

That's not well-formed XML - attributes must have a name and a value - so if you try to parse it with an XML parser you will get an error.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I deleted the lines you mentioned and reanalyzed the text and the program ran successfully. I just have one question, since I am not a professional programmer and I am not familiar with the structure of HTML, so is there a function in MATLAB that automatically detects and removes such cases that make parts of the HTML code unanalyzable? If not, can you provide a function for me? (Of course, it is easy to delete these items, the important thing is to recognize that I can't recognize the invalid items) .

Comment: Sorry, I don't know MATLAB.